# Why do I get "looks like we got no XML document" fault?

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I need to make a request to the "List" method of my WSDL.

In SOAP UI the following request works (So I know for sure there is nothing wrong with the server):

```
POST https://examplewsdl.com/mailwebservice/mtom/ HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8
Authorization: Basic [AUTH_TOKEN]
Content-Length: 298
Host: lms.example.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/16.0.1)

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:mail="http://www.examplewsdl.com/ems/mailwebservice">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <mail:ListRequest>
         <mail:accountId>123456789</mail:accountId>
      </mail:ListRequest>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am making a SOAP 1.2 request with the PHP SoapClient, but I get the error code "looks like we got no XML document" back.

This is what my request looks like now:

```
<?php
$wsdl = 'https://examplewsdl.com/mailwebservice/mtom/mailwebservice-mtom.wsdl';
$options = [
    'authentication' => SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC,
    'login' => '...',
    'password' => '...',
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
];

try {
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
    $res = $client->List(['accountId' => '123456789']);
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

I already tried answers in same like questions on Stack like this solution for MTOM message encoding: https://gist.github.com/pkmishra/2243055

But without success.

Comment: Well it looks like that XML is missing the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` line. Not sure if it should have one in this case, but it looks a little wrong, and sort of fits the error message

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ok, but how can this be added via the Client? Or at least how can I see what the XML body is that is sent to the server?